# How can I perform a server to server file transfer

Tags: ftp, transfer

I would like to copy a site which is currently being hosted live on an easyspace web domain to another domain that is hosted by the web company Parallels. I wondered if there was a way of doing this without fist taking the site down and copying the files back to the local server, then re-uploading them again.

If anyone has any advice on this, I would be most grateful!

Regards,

Robert Y

Comment: Also, I expect the MySQL database would be an issue here - any database whizzes out there who could advise as to what to do in this field?! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to check if fxp protocol (that is a protocol that supports file transfer between servers) is supported by both servers: but usually is disabled for security reasons. If it is active (make a question to your host admin) than you can use a fxp software as FlashFXP, SmartFTP or FTP Rush (Freeware) or similar sw.

Answer (score -1):

SUPER FAST:
For direct Server to Server file transfers: if you know your ftp url or ip address you can use FlashFXP (not related to adobe flash)

Make a zip file that contains all the live files on your target server. You can do this via command line or easier through your server's cPanel. Compression Time depends on your server's CPU speed and quantity & size of files.

Download a copy of FlashFXP it works well and has a free trial
http://www.flashfxp.com/download

Log-in to your target server, navigate to directory with your target files.
Log-in to your destination server, navigate to directory to store transfered files.

Once connected & directories are visually lined-up... just drag and drop desired files into desired directory on opposing server.

Overall transfer speed depends on internet backbone traffic & each servers connection + cpu speed & throttling controls between your two servers. GOOD NEWS the speed is NOT reliant on your cable modem's connection speed. No slow download and then even slower upload, just a clear straight shot to the other server.

This FlashFXP Server to Server video tutorial is nice --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XXQgeRWWRw